# logging handler in glib/gmessages.h

Tags: c, logging, glib

I'm trying to use [glib/gmessages.h](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Message-Logging.html) as logging system for my application. My problem is demonstrated by following piece of code:

trial.c:

```
#include <glib/gmessages.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_handler(const gchar* log_domain, GLogLevelFlags log_level,
                const gchar* message, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("My handler: %s", message);
}

int main()
{
    g_log_set_handler (LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL |
                                   G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION, my_handler, NULL);
    g_log(LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, "Hello 1\n");
    g_log(LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING | G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION, "Hello 2\n");
   return (0);
}
```

When compiled with

```
gcc trial.c -DLOG_DOMAIN=\"MY_APP\" `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

the output is:

```
~> ./a.out
My handler: Hello 1
(process:25133): MY_APP-WARNING (recursed) **: Hello 2
Aborted
```

Why isn't the second call to `g_log` handled by my handler?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

An abort signal is sent because you are using a bad parameter in your second call.

You must choose between `G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING` and `G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION` for logging with g_log.

I guess you can make 2 calls

```
g_log(LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION, "Hello 2\n");
g_log(LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, "Hello 2\n");
```

but I am  not sure it is a good practice.

The `G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING | G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION` parameter is bad.

Comment: I don't think that's right, even glib itself generates recursed warnings. Can you explain why do you think the combination of flags is bad? By the way, I understand why there is an abort signal. I don't understand, why my function isn't called.

Comment: First, the documentation of g_log. The variable name is log_level. In g_log_set_handler, the variable name is log_levels.

Comment: Secondly, a look at gmessage.c source code show that abort() is called. It explains why second log does not appear.

Comment: Okay, the code shows that the second log does not appear, but it does not explain why. Using `G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL` works normally, so why not `G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING | G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION` ? What am I supposed to do, if I need to handle recursed warnings? The code I posted is just a demonstration, as I said, glib generates such warnings itself.